# Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans, crud

Hello Im trying to make a CRUD using @RepositoryRestResource in my repository interface
and i have an error "Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController'"

IF I DELETE THE ANNOTATION @RepositoryRestResource in my repository interface WORKS NORMALLY

BUT ADDING IT, I GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR:

```
  Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2020-08-19 21:15:08.269 ERROR 14692 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Jonathan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/3.3.2.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySearchController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryEntityLinks]: Factory method 'entityLinks' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Path /users configured for com.restaurants.users.data.userRespository must only contain a single path segment!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
```

In the Repository interface looks like this

```
     @RepositoryRestResource(path = "/users")public interface userRespository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    
        @Query("select  u from UserEntity u where u.username=?1")
        UserEntity findByUsername(String username);
}
```

in my POM.xml i have

```
 <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

in my properties

```
#name of the service
spring.application.name=users
#port of the service on 0 in order to set a random port
server.port=${PORT:0}
#eureka instance
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
#enable devtools restart in every change
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
#adress of eureka server
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka


########SQL########
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/users?serverTimezone=America/Mexico_City
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

in my main method

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UsersApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UsersApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: The real error is `IllegalStateException: Path /users configured for com.restaurants.users.data.userRespository must only contain a single path segment!`, so remove the `/`, i.e. use `@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users")`

Answer (score 1):

You have to  mention path='endpoint name' without using '/' in @RepositoryRestResource. You have to use @RepositoryRestResource(path = **"users"**), it's direct spring MVC to create RESTful endpoints at **/user**